# How to load data dynamically into a html div from a mongoDb server using node.js

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

I would like to load data dynamically to html elements using data from mongoDb, I am running node.js on the backed, and would like to know the best practices when it comes to load the data, are there any premade-workflows that will help me do that, and how to ensure the secure delivery of the data.

I currently have static elements that are not changing and would like to fill them out using live data from the server.
I am not looking for code, but instead I want to know if there are any libraries dedicated to doing that, or if there are any workflows which can guide me to proper testing and deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For render you dynamic data into html in node JS, you have to use template engine library.
This is best and easy to implement solution in my eye.

Engines are :

1.EJS : Link [EJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs)

2.Express-handlebars : Link [express-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars)

3.Pug : Link [pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug)

There are more available what ever you want you can use.

Here are some link that help you :

How To use EJS : [EJS Use](https://%20https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application)

EJS Official : [EJS](https://ejs.co/)